# PHP Array Speed: Is 10,000 elements TOO MANY for accessing associative arrays in a timely manner?

Tags: php, arrays

Say you have an associative array of about 10,000 elements in size. Is this generally viewed as too BIG of an array and thus undesirable from the standpoint of fast webpage serving? What I want to do is this (And I want to do it fast without a noticable delay):

```
//assume $theArray has 10,000 elements
echo $theArray["product_4563"];
```

Comment: There is no too much or too few. Either your implementation satisfy your task limitations or not.

Comment: It's too many when you get 'out of memory' errors.

Comment: Not exactly the answer I was looking for...But, I guess I should clarify my objectives: I want to access the value in a really long (10000+ elems) assc. array AND not stall the browser for more than a second. Is this possible or not.

Comment: *(tipp)* http://matthewturland.com/2010/05/20/new-spl-features-in-php-5-3/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the "arrays" in PHP are actually Maps, or dictionaries.

The key is mapped to the value with a Hash table, so it's an O(1) access anyway.

Most languages support arrays in a way that the insert, remove, access or in O(1) like in a regular array.
Or else it wouldn't really be an array, and thus not named "Array".

Comment: adding to this: it might be a more of a memory issue then a speed issue.

Comment: An interesting side note is when copying an array, the copied will only use a fraction of memory (rather than the entire amount of memory required to actually store the array) until it is altered. Up until then, they are treated as reference to the same array.

Comment: I see. So it should not take a long time to access the value of a long array as long as I know the key. Thanks.

Comment: @Eric: Yes, in the average case it shouldn't take much time. If the hightly improbable case occurs that all your keys result in the same hash, performance is degraded to O(n), because a linear search must be done. But as I said: Highly improbable ;)

Answer (score 2):

Speed won't be your problem for the most part as PHP array element access is very fast. It's memory size you should be concerned about (especially if the individual elements contain a lot of data).

Loading in 10,000 elements to just echo one of them is not as efficient as it could be. This data should be stored in a database and you can just select the desired record, then echo it.

Speed will only come into play if you have many requests per second loading these large arrays or if the source of the data used to fill the array is dependent on external resources. With many simultaneous requests, your memory will approach exhaustion and your web server will start to crawl as it begins employing virtual memory.

Comment: might have many simultaneous requests to the page -- and if I use a database I will get a "too many connections" error, no?

Comment: @Eric - If you're getting that many simultaneous requests that it causes this problem, then you need to scale up your server farm... though for most sites that are smaller than facebook or google, you don't need to worry so much. How many hits/second are you getting at peak? dozens? hundreds? thousands?

Comment: @Eric: You're going to hit memory limit errors long, long before you would hit `too many connections` error. The point of using the database is it affords you very fast, efficient data searches, bypassing the need to load huge arrays into memory.

Comment: @Eric, @webbiedave: Unless Eric's using badly configured persistent connections which clog up his connection pool.

Comment: the Max Connections setting for my (shared) hosting account is like 25. I have gotten max connections warnings in the past..

Answer (score 0):

That's unpredictable to determine how long an operation will "stall the browser". The time taken to for the browser to render the page depends on much more than the time taken to execute a script. Regarding the speed of the actual operation it shouldn't take more than a millisecond or two. Check here for interesting [benchmarks](http://www.phpbench.com/), you'll notice all the results are in microseconds.